# Works on console project but not on ASP.NET project EF Core with MySql Connector

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a weird problem here. I'm trying to access a MySql database with Entity Framework Core.

It works on the .NET console. but when the same code runs on the web app it says.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Clone' in type 'MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.Internal.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL[TContext]
   at ConsoleApplication.EmployeesContextFactory.Create(String connectionString) in BooksController.cs:line 65
```

Here is my code

```
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EmployeesContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connectionString);

    var context = new EmployeesContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

It gives me the exception on the method `UseMySql()` The same exact code works fine in the console.

Also `connectionString, .NET Core version` and many of the constraints that I can think of are the same.

**EDIT**

Seeing the difference The ASP.NET project has following Nugets
[image]

The console app has the following,

[image]

Both projects show it's target framework as 2.0

What's the right way to solve this issue?

Comment: I think it's got to do with version difference.

Comment: @JohnKennedy Yeah. Is it possible to use .Net core 1.1 nugets in 2.0? If that’s possible it’ll solve the issue.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You should get v2.0 for the packages you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the current MySQL connector only supports .NET Core 1, you might not be able to use it with v2.
You could try this package at https://github.com/jasonsturges/mysql-dotnet-core